# How do you parse this JSON?

Tags: json, swift, codable

Hello I'm using the RetroAcheivements API to build a Swift Package. Here is the JSON response:

```json
{
    "recent": [
        [
            {
                "GameID": "11310",
                "ConsoleID": "12",
                "ConsoleName": "PlayStation",
                "Title": "Wild Arms",
                "ImageIcon": "/Images/058584.png",
                "LastPlayed": "2022-11-01 13:32:47",
                "NumPossibleAchievements": "156",
                "PossibleScore": "1075",
                "NumAchieved": "15",
                "ScoreAchieved": "80",
                "NumAchievedHardcore": 0,
                "ScoreAchievedHardcore": 0
            },
            {
                "GameID": "11332",
                "ConsoleID": "12",
                "ConsoleName": "PlayStation",
                "Title": "Final Fantasy Origins",
                "ImageIcon": "/Images/060249.png",
                "LastPlayed": "2022-10-29 07:01:53",
                "NumPossibleAchievements": "120",
                "PossibleScore": "945",
                "NumAchieved": "4",
                "ScoreAchieved": "18",
                "NumAchievedHardcore": 0,
                "ScoreAchievedHardcore": 0
            },
            {
                "GameID": "11248",
                "ConsoleID": "12",
                "ConsoleName": "PlayStation",
                "Title": "Xenogears",
                "ImageIcon": "/Images/049196.png",
                "LastPlayed": "2022-10-28 07:51:38",
                "NumPossibleAchievements": "82",
                "PossibleScore": "670",
                "NumAchieved": 0,
                "ScoreAchieved": 0,
                "NumAchievedHardcore": 0,
                "ScoreAchievedHardcore": 0
            },
            {
                "GameID": "11255",
                "ConsoleID": "12",
                "ConsoleName": "PlayStation",
                "Title": "Suikoden",
                "ImageIcon": "/Images/054686.png",
                "LastPlayed": "2022-10-28 04:55:52",
                "NumPossibleAchievements": "92",
                "PossibleScore": "800",
                "NumAchieved": "6",
                "ScoreAchieved": "30",
                "NumAchievedHardcore": 0,
                "ScoreAchievedHardcore": 0
            },
            {
                "GameID": "11320",
                "ConsoleID": "12",
                "ConsoleName": "PlayStation",
                "Title": "Gran Turismo",
                "ImageIcon": "/Images/060107.png",
                "LastPlayed": "2022-10-16 13:40:43",
                "NumPossibleAchievements": "68",
                "PossibleScore": "585",
                "NumAchieved": 0,
                "ScoreAchieved": 0,
                "NumAchievedHardcore": 0,
                "ScoreAchievedHardcore": 0
            },
            {
                "GameID": "319",
                "ConsoleID": "3",
                "ConsoleName": "SNES",
                "Title": "Chrono Trigger",
                "ImageIcon": "/Images/063507.png",
                "LastPlayed": "2022-10-11 15:50:15",
                "NumPossibleAchievements": "77",
                "PossibleScore": "600",
                "NumAchieved": 0,
                "ScoreAchieved": 0,
                "NumAchievedHardcore": 0,
                "ScoreAchievedHardcore": 0
            }
        ]
    ]
}
```

And here is my Swift model struct generated using Quicktype.io:

```swift
struct Recents: Codable {
    let recent: [[Recent]]
}


struct Recent: Codable {
    let gameID, consoleID, consoleName, title: String
    let imageIcon, lastPlayed: String
    let numPossibleAchievements, possibleScore: Achieved
    let numAchieved, scoreAchieved: Achieved
    let numAchievedHardcore, scoreAchievedHardcore: Achieved

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case gameID = "GameID"
        case consoleID = "ConsoleID"
        case consoleName = "ConsoleName"
        case title = "Title"
        case imageIcon = "ImageIcon"
        case lastPlayed = "LastPlayed"
        case numPossibleAchievements = "NumPossibleAchievements"
        case possibleScore = "PossibleScore"
        case numAchieved = "NumAchieved"
        case scoreAchieved = "ScoreAchieved"
        case numAchievedHardcore = "NumAchievedHardcore"
        case scoreAchievedHardcore = "ScoreAchievedHardcore"
    }
}

enum Achieved: Codable {
    case integer(Int)
    case string(String)

    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.singleValueContainer()
        if let x = try? container.decode(Int.self) {
            self = .integer(x)
            return
        }
        if let x = try? container.decode(String.self) {
            self = .string(x)
            return
        }
        throw DecodingError.typeMismatch(Achieved.self, DecodingError.Context(codingPath: decoder.codingPath, debugDescription: "Wrong type for Achieved"))
    }

    func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
        var container = encoder.singleValueContainer()
        switch self {
        case .integer(let x):
            try container.encode(x)
        case .string(let x):
            try container.encode(x)
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my HTTP request code:

```swift
func getRecentGames(User: String,KEY: String,OtherUser: String){
    let RECENT_URL = "https://ra.hfc-essentials.com/user_recent.php?user=+\(User)+&key=+\(KEY)+&member=\(OtherUser)&results=10&mode=json"
    print(RECENT_URL)
    let task = session.dataTask(with: URLRequest(url: URL(string: RECENT_URL)!)) { data, response, error in
        if let error = error{
            print(error)
        }
        if let data = data{
            do{
                let decodedData = try JSONDecoder().decode(Recents.self, from: data)
                    print(decodedData.recent.joined().first!.numAchieved)
            }
            catch{
                print(error)
            }
        }
    }
    task.resume()
}
```

How can I access the `NumAchievedHardcore` property, which can be an Int or a String sometimes? When I decode and access them like this:

```swift
print(decodedData.recent.joined().first!.numAchieved)
```

I get this output:

> string("15")

How can I access it normally so that it does not give `string()` or `int()` as output and instead gives only the Int or String values?

Comment: There is no issue with parsing the json if I understand this correctly but rather you need to learn how to handle an enum with associated values, see https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Enumerations.html#ID148, or change your model and decoding so the values are always decoded as Int (or String) but not a mix of the two.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this issue by adding the following property to the enum which can be used to access the int value easily

```
  var intValue: Int? {
        switch self {
        case .integer(let value): return value
        case .string(let value): return Int(value)
  }
```

Answer (score -1):

[Use This Link for Model Generate](https://www.json4swift.com/)

Use **Classic Swift Key/Value Dictionary**

You Get Model Like This :---

```
/* 
Copyright (c) 2022 Swift Models Generated from JSON powered by http://www.json4swift.com

Permission is hereby granted, free of charge, to any person obtaining a copy of this software and associated documentation files (the "Software"), to deal in the Software without restriction, including without limitation the rights to use, copy, modify, merge, publish, distribute, sublicense, and/or sell copies of the Software, and to permit persons to whom the Software is furnished to do so, subject to the following conditions:

The above copyright notice and this permission notice shall be included in all copies or substantial portions of the Software.

THE SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED "AS IS", WITHOUT WARRANTY OF ANY KIND, EXPRESS OR IMPLIED, INCLUDING BUT NOT LIMITED TO THE WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY, FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE AND NONINFRINGEMENT. IN NO EVENT SHALL THE AUTHORS OR COPYRIGHT HOLDERS BE LIABLE FOR ANY CLAIM, DAMAGES OR OTHER LIABILITY, WHETHER IN AN ACTION OF CONTRACT, TORT OR OTHERWISE, ARISING FROM, OUT OF OR IN CONNECTION WITH THE SOFTWARE OR THE USE OR OTHER DEALINGS IN THE SOFTWARE.
*/

import Foundation
 
/* For support, please feel free to contact me at https://www.linkedin.com/in/syedabsar */

public class Recent {
    public var gameID : String?
    public var consoleID : String?
    public var consoleName : String?
    public var title : String?
    public var imageIcon : String?
    public var lastPlayed : String?
    public var numPossibleAchievements : String?
    public var possibleScore : String?
    public var numAchieved : String?
    public var scoreAchieved : String?
    public var numAchievedHardcore : Int?
    public var scoreAchievedHardcore : Int?

/**
    Returns an array of models based on given dictionary.
    
    Sample usage:
    let recent_list = Recent.modelsFromDictionaryArray(someDictionaryArrayFromJSON)

    - parameter array:  NSArray from JSON dictionary.

    - returns: Array of Recent Instances.
*/
    public class func modelsFromDictionaryArray(array:NSArray) -> [Recent]
    {
        var models:[Recent] = []
        for item in array
        {
            models.append(Recent(dictionary: item as! NSDictionary)!)
        }
        return models
    }

/**
    Constructs the object based on the given dictionary.
    
    Sample usage:
    let recent = Recent(someDictionaryFromJSON)

    - parameter dictionary:  NSDictionary from JSON.

    - returns: Recent Instance.
*/
    required public init?(dictionary: NSDictionary) {

        gameID = dictionary["GameID"] as? String
        consoleID = dictionary["ConsoleID"] as? String
        consoleName = dictionary["ConsoleName"] as? String
        title = dictionary["Title"] as? String
        imageIcon = dictionary["ImageIcon"] as? String
        lastPlayed = dictionary["LastPlayed"] as? String
        numPossibleAchievements = dictionary["NumPossibleAchievements"] as? String
        possibleScore = dictionary["PossibleScore"] as? String
        numAchieved = dictionary["NumAchieved"] as? String
        scoreAchieved = dictionary["ScoreAchieved"] as? String
        numAchievedHardcore = dictionary["NumAchievedHardcore"] as? Int
        scoreAchievedHardcore = dictionary["ScoreAchievedHardcore"] as? Int
    }

        
/**
    Returns the dictionary representation for the current instance.
    
    - returns: NSDictionary.
*/
    public func dictionaryRepresentation() -> NSDictionary {

        let dictionary = NSMutableDictionary()

        dictionary.setValue(self.gameID, forKey: "GameID")
        dictionary.setValue(self.consoleID, forKey: "ConsoleID")
        dictionary.setValue(self.consoleName, forKey: "ConsoleName")
        dictionary.setValue(self.title, forKey: "Title")
        dictionary.setValue(self.imageIcon, forKey: "ImageIcon")
        dictionary.setValue(self.lastPlayed, forKey: "LastPlayed")
        dictionary.setValue(self.numPossibleAchievements, forKey: "NumPossibleAchievements")
        dictionary.setValue(self.possibleScore, forKey: "PossibleScore")
        dictionary.setValue(self.numAchieved, forKey: "NumAchieved")
        dictionary.setValue(self.scoreAchieved, forKey: "ScoreAchieved")
        dictionary.setValue(self.numAchievedHardcore, forKey: "NumAchievedHardcore")
        dictionary.setValue(self.scoreAchievedHardcore, forKey: "ScoreAchievedHardcore")

        return dictionary
    }

}
```

Use This Model to fetch json data from API response Like This :----

```
let dataList = [Recent]()


    func getRecentGames(User: String,KEY: String,OtherUser: String){
        let RECENT_URL = "https://ra.hfc-essentials.com/user_recent.php?user=+\(User)+&key=+\(KEY)+&member=\(OtherUser)&results=10&mode=json"
        print(RECENT_URL)
        
        //URLSession.data
        
        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: URLRequest(url: URL(string: RECENT_URL)!)) { data, response, error in

            if let error = error{
                print(error)
            }
            
            do {
                if let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: []) as? NSDictionary {
                    print("Response: \(json)")
                    
                    if let data = json.value(forKey: "recent") as? [NSArray] {
                        self.dataList = Recent.modelsFromDictionaryArray(array: data[0])
                    }
                    
                    
                    print(self.dataList.first?.numAchieved)
                    
                    // self.mainResponse(json)
                } else {
                    let jsonStr = NSString(data: data!, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)// No error thrown, but not NSDictionary
                    print("Error could not parse JSON: \(jsonStr)")
                    // self.eroorResponse(jsonStr!)
                }
            } catch let parseError {
                print(parseError)// Log the error thrown by `JSONObjectWithData`
                let jsonStr = NSString(data: data!, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)
                print("Error could not parse JSON: '\(jsonStr)'")
                // self.eroorResponse(jsonStr!)
            }
            
        }
        task.resume()
    }
```

Comment: I'm unable to use response.value  it says Type of expression is ambiguous without more context

Comment: Use Alamofire for API calling instead of URLSession

Comment: Hello, pls check i update my answer and let me know is it work for you ?

Comment: Please stop suggesting `NS...` classes. This is Swift.